# c# Pre-processor directive scope

Tags: c#, scope, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm looking to use:

```
#define
```

and

```
#if
```

to allow me to simulate potentially absent hardware during unit tests. What are the rules for using the `#define` statements?

i.e. what is its default scope? can I change the scope of the directive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Chris said, the scope of #define is just the file. (It's worth noting that this isn't the same as "the class" - if you have a partial type, it may consist of two files, one of which has symbol defined and one of which doesn't!

You can also define a symbol project-wide, but that's done with [project properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7f8bfy4.aspx) or a [compiler switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) rather than being specified in source code.

Comment: Note VS2017: a project-wide symbol (set in Project/Properties) seems *not* to work with Unit test projects. Very inconvenient.

Comment: @Goodies: What do you mean by "not work"? The compiler shouldn't care at all whether it's a unit test property or not. The unit test project won't see anything defined in the production project, of course.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x(VS.71).aspx), its scope is the file

Answer (score 1):

Although could you not go down the route of Mock objects, ala [Mock.Rhinos](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Chris mentioned, its scope is the whole file. You can use the defined keyword anywhere in the file.

i.e;

```
#define something
... some code ...
```

and in any method, class body or namespace, you could use it like;

```
#if something
  ... some conditional code ...
#else
  ... otherwise ...
#endif
```